# How to call an external function from within casper.start or casper.thenOpen

Tags: javascript, casperjs, function-call

I am trying to split the following code such that the callback function which is stored in its own file.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start("http://www.google.com/", function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});
casper.run(); // "Returns Google"
```

Following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538463/how-to-pass-data-from-the-then-methods-in-casperjs), I define a function in a separate file called "getPageTitle.js";

```
function getPageTitle(casper) {
    casper.echo(casper.getTitle());
}
exports.getPageTitle = getPageTitle;
```

and call the function in another file called "main.js" by passing the CasperJS object into the function directly;

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var casperFunctions = require('./getPageTitle.js');
casper.start("http://www.google.com/", casperFunctions.getPageTitle(casper));
# Error: CasperError: Casper is not started, can't execute `getTitle()`
```

Further, if I replace the last line in the above with a `thenOpen()` call;

```
casper.start();
casper.thenOpen("http://www.google.com/", casperFunctions.getPageTitle(casper));
```

The above code does not throw errors; CasperJS is able to navigate to the website, but the page title "Google" is not returned.

Could someone please shed light on why this doesn't behave as I expect. This seems like a natural way to modularize functions that CasperJS would call once pages are loading, but am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The execution of CasperJS is asynchronous. `start()` and all `then*()` and `wait*()` functions are asynchronous step functions. That means that you're only on the page inside of such as step.

When you look at your `getPageTitle()` and how it is called, you should notice that you're not passing a step function into `casper.start()`, but instead you're immediately calling `getPageTitle()`. At that time, the execution hasn't even begun, because the scheduled steps begin executing as soon as `run()` is called. By calling `getPageTitle()`, you're trying to access the title of about:blank which is *blank*.

**First version:**

```
function getPageTitle(casper) {
    return function(){
        casper.echo(casper.getTitle());
    };
}
```

Now you're passing a step function into `start()` which will be evaluated asynchronously.

**Second version:**

Keep in mind that you can use `this` inside of a step function to refer to `casper`. This is a better way to do this, because you don't need to pass the reference explicitly:

```
function getPageTitle() {
    return function(){
        this.echo(this.getTitle());
    };
}
```

and call it like this:

```
casper.start("http://www.google.com/", casperFunctions.getPageTitle());
```

**Third version:**

If you the function doesn't need any arguments, then you don't need a wrapper function. You can pass it directly:

```
function getPageTitle() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
}
```

and call it like this:

```
casper.start("http://www.google.com/", casperFunctions.getPageTitle);
```

Comment: Just to confirm my understanding; am i right in thinking that under my original method, `getPageTitle` was being run while casper.start was retrieving the url, and hence nothing got returned?

Secondly - what is it about adding the `function()` wrapper that ensures `getPageTitle()` is only run once the page is returned from `.start()`?

Apologies if this is somewhat basic but sync/async calls are still a bit confusing. I read another somewhere else of yours where you refer to IIFE's. Is the function wrapper equivalent to this?

Comment: No, `start()` only schedules a step to open a URL. The whole execution only begin when `run()` is called. At that time your `getPageTitle()` already ran and tried to access the title from about:blank.

Answer (score 1):

```
casper.start("http://www.google.com/", casperFunctions.getPageTitle(casper));
```

doesn't work, because you're passing the result of calling `casperFunctions.getPageTitle(casper)` as the callback parameter to casper.start

I think you should be able to do this instead

```
casper.start("http://www.google.com/", casperFunctions.getPageTitle.bind(casper));
```

Comment: Might not work with PhantomJS 1.x, because `Function.prototype.bind` is not implemented.

Comment: I should've looked to see what `casperjs` was I guess

Comment: CasperJS does have a shim for `Function.prototype.bind`, but it's a very basic one and may not work as expected.